# why is openat() needed to avoid a two-step race condition with stat and then open()?

Tags: linux-kernel

The explanation at

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

about why `openat` is needed, reads in part:

> **openat()** allows an application to avoid race conditions that
>      could occur when using **open()** to open files in directories other than
>      the current working directory.  These race conditions result from the
>      fact that some component of the directory prefix given to **open()**
>      could be changed in parallel with the call to **open()**.  Suppose, for
>      example, that we wish to create the file *path/to/xxx.dep* if the file
>      *path/to/xxx* exists.  The problem is that between the existence check
>      and the file creation step, path or to (which might be symbolic
>      links) could be modified to point to a different location.

I don't see why this race is a problem. If an app wants to check for the existence of some file and if so, create a different file, then, of course these are two steps, and the app either should ensure that nothing interferes in between, or accept the consequences of doing a two-step operation. Only if a single call to `open()` could cause a race condition, might some other syscall, such as `openat()` be needed. Otherwise, this is not for syscalls to solve, but it is an application's responsibility to deal with.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: I already upvoted and favorited this, but I thought you'd like to know that this kind of question is why I still visit SO so often. It made me think and learn, instead of just debug someone's code. Thanks for taking the time to ask it.

Comment: @skrrgwasme thank you very much I appreciate and I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**
`openat()` allows you to lock down an entire directory path, resolving the race condition only once, then safely open files relative to that path without worrying about race conditions.

**Details**
You are correct that the race condition is still the responsibility of your program to anticipate and handle, but the `openat()` function allows you to *only do it once* for multiple files. If you want to open multiple files within the same directory, you *could* do it with individual calls to `open()`, but you will have to expect and handle the race condition every time. Instead, with `openat()`, you can grab a file descriptor to the parent directory first, which will prevent other processes from modifying or removing that path. You can now use `openat()` to open multiple files relative to that locked path safely, without worrying about the race conditions that opening absolute paths normally entails.

**Other Use Case**
Also note that the race condition isn't necessarily between your program opening files and other programs changing or deleting paths - it's also between threads within your program. `openat()` is useful when you want to work with relative paths and are in a multithreaded environment. Remember that if you change your working directory in one thread, it changes it for the entire process and its threads.

So when you fork off multiple threads, they can each grab a file descriptor for different directories, and use `openat()` with those *directory* file descriptors and relative paths from them to open files, without worrying about what the other threads are doing with the whole processes' working directory, or maintaining a load of absolute paths.

This use case is described by the second note in the man page for `openat`:

> Second, openat() allows the implementation of a per-thread "current working directory", via file descriptor(s) maintained by the application. (This functionality can also be obtained by tricks based on the use of /proc/self/fd/dirfd, but less efficiently.

**Sidenote**
I don't want to get too deep into a discussion of what responsibilities should be assumed by system calls because it will get subjective, but note that `openat` doesn't really *resolve* race conditions - you can still have one when you try to lock down the parent directory, and that's entirely your program's responsibility to handle. It is a tool to help you *prevent* race conditions, after you've achieved resolution once. I think that's a useful and reasonable mechanism to include in an OS as a system call.

Comment: my question was:  is there something wrong with that documentation passage, or if not, what am not understanding from it.  Is your answer in fact, that the documentation I am quoting, is incorrect, that what they are saying, is not a good reason for `openat`, that the reason is in fact different.  That is what I want to know.

Comment: OK thank you.  I did not quote the second part, because, I understood it.  I was just thinking, it should _only_ be the second part, that the first part was spurious.

Comment: @MarkGaleck I hope my edits clarified the first note (which is what your question was focusing on anyway). Even the initial `open` call to get the directory locked down in the first place is subject to the same race conditions, but once you have it, you are now safe from that point forward. That's something that `open` alone can't give you - potential race conditions are *always* present.